# how to connect python to cassandra that run with docker

Tags: python, docker, cassandra, docker-toolbox

I want get online data and save to cassandra keyspace. I read this guide, https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-cassandra-on-windows, to run cassandra. It seems easy, but I get error that related to jdk. So, I tried different way. I tried with docker-toolbox (windows 8.1). I run cassndra by these steps in docker-toolbox shell:

```
$ docker run --name some-cassandra2 --network some-network -d cassandra:latest

$ docker run -it --network some-network --rm cassandra cqlsh some-cassandra2
```

[image]

```
cqlsh>create keyspace CityInfo with replication = {'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor':2};

cqlsh>use CityInfo;

cqlsh> CREATE TABLE cities (id int,name text,country text,PRIMARY KEY(id));

cqlsh> CREATE TABLE users (username text,name text,age int,PRIMARY KEY(username));
```

Now, I want get online data and save to cities and users table with python code. I get online data. I try to connect with this code:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
cluster = Cluster(['172.18.0.2'],port=9042)
session = cluster.connect('cityinfo',wait_for_all_pools=False)
session.execute('USE cityinfo')
rows = session.execute('SELECT * FROM users')
for row in rows:
        print(row.age,row.name,row.username)
```

But I see error:

```
File "cassandra\cluster.py", line 3533, in cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection._reconnect_internal

NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'172.18.0.2:9042': OSError(None, "Tried connecting to [('172.18.0.2', 9042)]. Last error: timed out")})
```

I tried several way. For example, I tried with other `ip` sush as 127.0.0.1:9042, or I added -p7000:7000 when runing cassandra to connect container port to device port. but I can't.
Please guide me. What is the problem?

Comment: Try using the container name instead of the ip

Comment: In python code? I Tried. Doesn't work.

Comment: Where is the client code running?  The container-private IP addresses are unreachable in almost all environments.  From another container, it needs to be on the same Docker network, and the `cqlsh` invocation in the question is right.  From outside Docker, on Docker Toolbox, you need the VM's IP address.

Comment: I I worked all day on it. First, I wanted run cassandra on docker and python code in spyder. But as you mentioned, it's impossible. Then, I read different sources and tested them. One of them has been explained at this https://towardsdatascience.com/getting-started-with-apache-cassandra-and-python-81e00ccf17c9 . In this address, python code run on docker shell. I tried it step by step as mentioned, with two method. First I runed python code as container. It released same error. Second, I runed python code directly. It can't import cassandra-driver. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest running your Python code from a container running on the same network, thus you can use the container name instead of the IP address directly in Python. I was able to run your code with no problem doing the following.

I created a docker container running Python, also running on `some-network`.

```sh
docker run -it --rm --network some-network python:3.8-slim bash
```

Proceeded to install cassandra-driver inside the container.

```sh
pip install cassandra-driver
```

Filled some dummy data in the `users` table and proceeded to open a Python terminal.

```py
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
cluster = Cluster(['some-cassandra2'], port=9042)
session = cluster.connect('cityinfo',wait_for_all_pools=False)
session.execute('USE cityinfo')
rows = session.execute('SELECT * FROM users')
for row in rows:
    print(row.age,row.name,row.username)
```

Notice that the only difference with your code is this line where I use the container name instead of the IP address:

```sh
cluster = Cluster(['some-cassandra2'], port=9042)
```